# laravel foreign key column naming convention

Tags: laravel, model, foreign-keys

I have a `LessonGroup` model and its tabel name is `lesson_groups` . if i want to use this table `id` in another tabel as a foreign key, what column name should i select that Laravel could distinguish it automatically as a [foreign key](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) to `lesson_group` table?

```
lesson_groups
   id
   name
 -----------------------------------------
fields
  id
  //foreign key to lesson_groups(what should be the name of this column?)
  name
```

Comment: `lesson_group_id` doesn't work

Comment: The lesson_groups table will have a column for id. A table that references (i.e. a relation) to a LessonGroup should have a lesson_group_id. See below an example of defining the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is an excerpt from the [Laravel Eloquent Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one):

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by **examining the name of the relationship method** and suffixing the method name with `_id`.

So for the naming convention to work seamlessly, you would need to have a relation like this defined in your `Field` model:

```php
public function lesson_group()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\LessonGroup');
}
```

Comment: Also: `public function lessonGroup() { return $this->hasOne(App\LessonGroup::class); }`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is Laravel pluralize the table names from Model name. eg: `LessonGroup` model will make the table `lesson_groups` (via Migration).
So the proper foreign key field name would be `lesson_group_id`?

Comment: The convention is to *not* pluralize the foreign key, so `lesson_group_id` is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

A good naming convention is the model name with underscores, followed by the id with an underscore. For example, FishingBoat would be fishing_boat_id.

Laravel will automatically assume that the foreign and/or local keys are in this format, unless defined otherwise.

Comment: yes,of course i have done it , but i'm asking about naming convention. `lesson_group_id` doesn't work

Comment: When you define the foreign key as above, there is no requirement for the name of the column. The lesson_group_id is a good naming convention. What's not working?

Comment: i wont to set the name of foreing key column as the second parameter when i'm defining a relation: `return $this->belongsTo('App\LessonGroup','lesson_group_id')`

Comment: Eloquent will automatically assume the foreign key to be lesson_group_id. You can keep this as belongsTo('App\LessonGroup')